# Мне кучу раз исправили мой пост, а затем вовсе заблокировали. Сделайте с этим беспределом что-нибудь!

Tags: поддержка, правки, блокировка

Я задал жизненно важный вопрос, который тут же стали чем-то там обвешивать и редактировать, не давая мне высказать свою мысль. А теперь и вовсе заблокировали. Кто-нибудь, остановите этот беспредел и восстановите справедливость! Я требую разблокировки и снятия пометок с вопроса. [Вот мой заблокированный пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698537/mysql-is-not-running-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5-xampp-%D0%BD%D0%B0-linux-debian-%D0%9D%D0%95-%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A2#698537)

Comment: И как писать тут личные сообщения? Я даже не могу высказать заблокировавшей мой пост персоне всё что о ней думаю.

Comment: Он ещё и всю переписку стёр, там тонны полезной информации было!!!!! Господи, пожалуйста, остановите того безумца

Comment: Надо было еще и забанить, за оскорбления.

Comment: Не надо требовать. Вам отвечали в комментариях по делу. Да и комментарии в чате, а не совсем удалены

Comment: @АлексейШиманский только вот пользователей <20 rep в чат не пускает

Comment: @PashaPash пускает, только readonly. А забанен был участник за соответствующее поведение уже в том самом конкретном чате и в том вопросе

Answer (score 11):

#### Как ни неприятно, справедливость торжествует прямо сейчас.

Видите ли, в ваш вопрос вносили **улучшающие** правки, причём *только удаляя, ничего не добавляя* ([см. историю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/698537/revisions)), ни о каком "обвешивании" речи идти не может. Ваше недовольство не имеет отношения к вопросу и никого, кроме вас, не интересует, но при этом нарушает ["политику дружелюбия"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice):

> **Грубость и оскорбления – это плохо.** Тон ваших сообщений должен быть таким же, как при разговоре с тем, кого вы уважаете и от кого ждёте встречного уважения.

Поэтому выражениям этого недовольства не место в вопросе, да и на сайте в целом тоже. Высказать недовольство системой *в конструктивной форме* (с явной формулировкой проблемы и аргументами, объясняющими вред от неё) можно здесь, на Мете, где сообщество может ознакомиться с вашими доводами, предоставить своё видение ситуации и аргументы, и по итогам принять или не принять меры.

То, что вы систематически действуете против этих правок (т. е. "устраиваете войну правок"), является **вандализмом**, и модератор отреагировал на это соответствующе: блокировкой вопроса до тех пор, пока вы не продемонстрируете намерений его не портить.

---

Что касается самого вопроса. То, что он для вас "жизненно важен" это исключительно ваша беда. Оказание здесь личной помощи по *небольшим* проблемам является лишь поводом для публикации вопросов здесь, но не самоцелью.

Вы же столкнулись с **большой** проблемой, для которой есть парочка небольших решений, перечисленных в вопросе, к которому придубликатили ваш.

Если вас не устраивают небольшие и простые решения, то ваш вопрос всё равно подлежит закрытию, как "слишком общий".