# Открытое обсуждение проблем сообщества

Tags: обсуждение

Предлагаю сообществу обсудить: "А что, собственно у нас не в порядке?"...

По результатам обсуждения можно будет сформировать субъективную картину настроений активного слоя сообщества(тех, кто пожелает высказаться), проанализировать её и приступить к "лечению" - не бывает безвыходных ситуаций.

В ответе предполагается увидеть Ваше мнение о том, что сломано и как, с Вашей точки зрения это следует чинить.

Если с Вашей точки зрения - сообщество здорово и ничего "чинить" не нужно - не стесняйтесь высказать эту точку зрения.

Приблизительный план, (*который можно полностью проигнорировать*)

1. Зачем Вы здесь, что привлекает Вас в сообществе?
2. В чём Вы видите основные проблемы сообщества на текущий момент?
3. Что, по Вашему, неправильно в поведении/действиях управляющего/модераторов?
4. Что и кому следует предпринять, чтобы это исправить?
5. Верите ли Вы, что сообщество в состоянии преодолеть эти проблемы?

Также, прошу быть максимально корректными, проявлять взаимоуважение. Ведь если у нас получится, мы продолжим дружно сосуществовать развивая ресурс. Здесь нет врагов.

И самое главное - если Вы не выскажетесь, Вы не будете услышаны!
Если Вам есть что сказать - не молчите.

---

*Ввиду важности каждого голоса настойчиво прошу у участников соблюдать [правила данного сайта](/help).*

*Ко всему прочему, хочу предостеречь - субъективное мнение конкретных участников - это субъективное мнение конкретных участников. Оно ни в коем случае не претендует на истину в последней инстанции, покуда не подкреплено фактами*

---

**Обновление—пояснение от управляющего**

Этот вопрос сам по себе не решит проблемы. Он нужен для того, чтобы вас могли услышать другие участники сообщества, которые, возможно, испытывают те же переживания, что и вы! В этой связи хочется отметить:

1. Если вы видите интересные или непонятные для вас идеи, чувства, предложения, пожалуйста, расскажите автору ответа об этом! Задавайте как можно больше уточнений в комментариях — дайте возможность автору продумать, доработать или даже поменять исходную мысль!
2. Ваши мысли и субъективные переживания остаются вашими, даже после публикации. Никто кроме вас не сможет в полной мере понять их, оценить их важность и тем более продумать реализацию. Этот вопрос нужен для коллективного рассмотрения ваших субъективных переживаний. Если вы просто расскажете коллегам, например, что «я бы хотел, чтобы все решения на сайте принимались только голосованием», голосования не появятся на сайте. Чтобы это произошло, вам лично (или тем, кто вам сопереживает) необходимо продумать идею, обосновать необходимость, показать как она может улучшить систему в контексте миссии и *опубликовать отдельную инициативу с вашим предложением* (дополнительно: смотрите описание метки [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info)).

Еще раз обращу внимание, этот вопрос — диалог между участниками. Результат диалога — наиболее важные для сообщества инициативы, опубликованные отдельно, согласно правилам Сети.

Comment: если человек видит конкретную решаемую проблему, то отдельное обсуждение на Мета под эту конкретную проблему с предложением  возможных решений можно открыть. Иначе, если нет конкретной/решаемой проблемы, то только токсичное словоблудие остаётся.

Comment: @jfs, цель данной публикации(всего вопроса) - собрать анамнез у недовольных. Впоследствии, в планах инициировать обсуждение по каждому пункту, в рамках конкретных озвученных проблем, да. Для того, чтобы что-то обсуждать - это что-то нужно обозначить. Если бы не было необходимости в этой "инициации", мы бы, скорее всего, к ней не пришли.

Comment: @jfs: Если вы немного присмотритесь к тому, что происходит в сообществе, то вы поймёте, что попытки подавить критику под грифом «это токсичное словоблудие» приводит к расколу сообщетсва и потере связи тех, кто принимает решение, с реальностью. Ваша эмоциональная оценка вредит сайту.

Comment: @VladD это не эмоции, а отображение многолетнего опыта обсуждений на сайте.

Comment: @jfs: Попытки механического переноса опыта en.SO на ru.SO вредят. Это en.SO может позволить себе наплевать на проблемы участников — ещё придут. А на ru.SO такого нет, у нас мало отвечающих. Вот у вас, например, в среднем по пол-ответа в день.

Comment: @VladD: не вижу связи с моим комментарием. В подобных дискуссиях, вы поддались на манипуляции провокаторов-троллей (осознано/не осознано их стиль переняли). Пустая риторика вместо конструктивных обсуждений, направленных на решение реальных проблем (в частности: как сделать сайт более привлекательным для людей, которые отвечают на вопросы). Тёмная сила соблазнительна -- легко забыть о грани между манипуляцией и убеждением. Убеждение -- хорошо. Манипуляции -- плохо¶ Если у вас есть идеи по какой-то конкретной проблеме, то конкретную проблему и пути её решения и стоит обсуждать.

Comment: @jfs: Вы почему-то считаете, что люди, которые высказывают проблемы в том стиле, который вам не нравится, заведомо злонамерены. Оттого, что вы назовёте меня провокатором, проблемы не решатся. Хотите помочь — переформулируйте проблему по другому **сами**, так, как вам кажется конструктивным. Не можете — не раскалывайте сообщество по линии «плохие участники, которые озвучивают проблему»/«хорошие участники, которые молчат».

Comment: @VladD все три утверждения ложны: 1- не считаю 2- не называл 3- молчать не заставлял

Comment: @jfs: Если вы используете термин «токсичное словоблудие», вам стоит объяснить, вы имеете в виду проблемы, опубликованные ниже (и это тогда будет и пунктом 1, и пунктом 3), или говорите о гипотетических каких-то вопросах (тогда стоит выражаться яснее, чтобы не _обидеть самого обидчивого_).

Answer (score 13):

**Проблема в излишней податливости участников на провокации, в излишней "импульсивности" управляющего, а также недостаточной освещённости существующих проблем, слабой обратной связи**

---

Я был участником enSO довольно давно, мне всегда нравилось помогать другим решать их задачи.
Во-первых, это даёт ощущение дополнительной полезности - таким образом мы развиваем культуру программирования.
Во-вторых, это позволяет всё время быть в тренде, в курсе реальных задач, с которыми сталкиваются твои коллеги.
В-третьих, когда у меня возникают какие-то нетривиальные проблемы - мне всегда есть куда обратиться. Одна голова хорошо, а миллион лучше)

Я был очень рад, когда увидел ruSO в area51. ХешКод я как-то пропустил...
Это позволило мне получить практически то же самое, что на enSO, но без языкового барьера. Это же прекрасно

---

Мне очень неприятно было видеть, как из-за каких-то мелочей, сообщество вдруг начало распадаться. Люди придумали себе проблемы, о которых никто никогда тут не задумывался, как то "отсутствие реальной демократии" или "неудобный механизм опротестования банов".
Никто ведь не уходит из вк, потому что администрации плевать на их личное мнение? Помните "ДуровВерниСтену"? Для чего на сайте вопросов и ответов демократия, к слову основные механизмы которой тут присутствуют? Та же Мета, на которой мы ранее много раз сообща принимали различные решения, как то новые причины закрытия и т.п. Принимали не единолично, а через КМ доносили свои пожелания до администрации, где либо соглашались, либо думали над компромиссным решением. Да если подумать, в реальной политике сила демократического "голоса" порой меньше)

---

Основная проблема на мой взгляд, в излишней податливости участников на провокации, в излишней "импульсивности" управляющего, а также недостаточной освещённости существующих проблем, слабой обратной связи.

В момент, когда стихийно образовавшаяся группа во главе с забаненным товарищам начала требовать обнародовать обстоятельства блокировки - не стоило мешкать, существует правило, что защита конфиденциальности распространяется только на те случаи, когда раскрытия не желает "пострадавший участник". Показали всё как есть, так мол и так, пользователя предупреждали, выдали бан.
Чрезмерная защита демонстративно не желавшего защиты участника сыграла злую шутку - люди поверили в единственную доступную им версию происходящего - этого никак нельзя было допускать.
Усугубила ситуацию также цензура в отношении ссылок на альтернативную платформу общения - хотя она и была вероятным источником распространения некорректной версии событий, сам факт цензуры только усилил интерес к ней, а уровень доверия к управляющему упал неоправданно низко.
Упал настолько, что когда была опубликована официальная версия событий - в неё попросту никто не поверил.

---

Что можно сделать в этой ситуации? Выдам рекурсивное умозаключение, но это моё мнение - поможет только диалог. Т.е. открытое обсуждение с участниками проблем, как они их видят. Для этого нужен шаг с обеих сторон, со стороны управляющего, чтобы выслушать любые мнения, какими бы они ни были, а со стороны участников, чтобы максимально корректно и обоснованно высказать свои недовольства/претензии.

---

Я считаю, что у нас тут сообщество разработчиков, людей, которые умеют шевелить мозгами. Они в состоянии взвесить все за и против, понять мотивы управляющего, модераторов, отдельных участников. И прийти, наконец, за стол переговоров, чтобы выяснить, существуют ли в действительности те проблемы, которые мешают сообществу. И осознав, что неразрешаемых проблем тут нет, продолжить развивать ресурс.

Comment: У нас больше нет управляющего.

Comment: Вообще говоря, есть. Просто он теперь не только наш)

Answer (score 10):

**Отсутствие локализованных правил**

Правила, которые обсуждаются в чуждой большей части сообщества* части сайтов (Meta.SE, например), внезапно становятся правилами и для нас. Таким образом, правила навязываются сообществу без возможности обсуждения. С точки зрения большей части сообщества, неактивной на Метамете, правила просто сбрасываются сверху.

Вследствие этого, правила и их изменения не отражают проблемы нашей части сообщества и их динамику.

Кроме того, многие правила имеют смысл для менталитета других стран, и совершенно неприменимы к нам. В качестве примера упомяну [попытку ввести запрет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4486/10105) на использование устойчивого в течение сотни лет фразеологизма «как белый человек».

Затем, вследствие малочисленности русскоязычного сообщества добиться какого-либо важного исключительно для нас результата на Метамете практически невозможно: голоса англоязычных пользователей перевешивают на два порядка.

Отсутствие локализованных правил приводит к тому, что правила для многих участников (по моей личной оценке) являются слабо легитимными, и лишь отсутствие строгости и контроля в их проведении в жизнь, а следовательно — фактическая необязательность их к исполнению мирят сообщество с этими правилами.

---

*Поскольку на нашем сайте находятся во многом те, кто предпочитает общение на русском

Comment: Я бы ещё уточнил, про иронию которую видимо скоро нам спустят в супнаборе правил бинайс2, но наверное это достойно отдельного вопроса на нашей мете, просто что-то никто не хочет связываться с этой темой.

Comment: @AK: Сможете написать это отдельным ответом?

Comment: @AK: Потому что _кое-кто_ ненавидит иронию и даже простое высказывание несогласия (которое называет _пассивной агрессией_ и _зловредным шумом_). Кто именно, говорить не буду, чтобы не получить обвинение в личных выпадах.

Comment: @AK иронию и сарказм хотят запретить, угу. Грустно это =/

Comment: `"фактическая необязательность их к исполнению мирят сообщество с этими правилами"` -- будем надеяться, что такое продлится достаточно долго

Answer (score 10):

Давайте попробуем сверхкратко собрать предъявленные тезисы:

- Отсутствие локализованных правил [VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7577/176064)
- У сообщества нет представителей в диалоге с администрацией [VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7569/176064)
- Администрация запрещает высказывание альтернативных мнений и умерщвляет сообщество [Athari](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7591/176064)
- Слишком свободная интерпретация правил, и расхождения в ней между разными частями сообщества, а также, традиционно, между сообществом и администрацией [VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7599/176064)
- Слишком мягкая политика в отношении людей, которые явно не удосужились ознакомиться с правилами, пишут откровенный треш в виде вопросов и так далее [Peter Samokhin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7574/176064)
- Навязчивый бинайс [Dmitry](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7584/176064)
- Редактирование моих сообщений без спроса [Diskyp](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7573/176064)

Когда соберём полный список, можно будет подумать, что из этого имеет смысл обсуждать и, собственно, приступить к самому обсуждению...

---

*Ответ общий. Здесь только список, чеклист. Все пункты должны присутствовать/быть раскрыты в ответах рядом.*

Answer (score 9):

**У сообщества нет представителей в диалоге с администрацией**

К сожалению, модераторы на данный момент не могут полноценно выполнять эту роль, поскольку, если я правильно понимаю, они обязаны иметь общую, согласованную с администрацией, точку зрения. Этим самым в случае конфликта сообщества с администрацией у сообщества нет никакой защиты. Кроме того, модераторы могут быть сняты или забанены администрацией в любой момент без обсуждения с сообществом, и, следовательно, особенно бесполезны при конфликте сообщества и администрации.

Я считаю, что сообществу нужны представители, которые обладали бы иммунитетом к санкциям руководства, были бы голосом сообщества, и защищали бы его. Это могут быть как модераторы, так и новый вид представителей.

Необходимо обеспечить, чтобы представители сообщества поддерживали сообщество. Для этого необходим контроль со стороны сообщества, и возможность как назначить новых представителей, если сообщество посчитает это нужным, так и снять представителя, который по каким-то причинам не защищает выбравшее его сообщество.

Также, я бы хотел, чтобы компания прислушивалась к голосу сообщества, озвученному представителями, и чтобы их слово имело более чем совещательный вес. Конкретный формат этого я бы хотел обсудить на Мете, если принципиальное согласие будет получено.

Отрицательное решение по данному вопросу со стороны компании для меня будет означать, что компания относится к сообществу лишь как к бесплатным поставщикам контента, и подымет дальнейшие вопросы.

Comment: "Модераторы не могут выполнять эту роль, поскольку, если я правильно понимаю, они обязаны иметь общую, согласованную с администрацией точку зрения" - нет, вы понимаете неправильно. Модераторы выбираются сообщестом, и являются представителями сообщества, а не администрации (команды SE). Модераторы не обязаны иметь общую с администрацией точку зрения (и достаточно часто не имеют).

Comment: Я к тому, что у нас уже есть институт избираемых сообществом модераторов (которые представляют сообщество, а не SE). Может быть проще потребовать иммунитет для них, а не вводить параллельную систему?

Comment: @PashaPash, поддерживаю. Не понимаю, зачем нужна ещё одна роль представителей сообщества, когда по идее она принадлежит модераторам. Тогда уж логичнее иммунитет давать именно модераторам, а не каким-то её представителям.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А имеют ли право модераторы быть не согласными с администрацией и отстаивать изменения в правилах сайта для удобства своих избирателей?

Comment: @VladD, даже если представить, что нет (хотя, вроде бы это не так), то почему это право надо давать кому-то ещё, а не им?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Если модераторам нельзя поддерживать сообщество, то нужен кто-то, кто будет поддерживать сообщество против администрации. Если же модераторам можно поддерживать сообщество, почему тогда они обязаны придерживаться общего мнения?

Comment: «если я правильно понимаю, они обязаны иметь общую, согласованную с администрацией, точку зрения» — нет, не обязаны, мы не улей. Довольно часто мы имеем совсем другую точку зрения и отстаиваем её.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Тем не менее, не далее как вчера в чате Николас заявил, что модераторы и администрация «заодно» — кому верить?

Comment: @VladD можно ссылку?

Comment: @VladD Николас не заявлял, что модераторы и администрация заодно. Он просто сказал, что бан и снятие модератора - это ситуация, которой возникать не должно. Это не означает, что точка зрения модераторов всегда должна совпадать с точкой зрения администрации.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ну хотя бы: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45921814#45921814 (и обсуждение выше).

Comment: @VladD «заодно» ≠ «за одно», как мне кажется.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это да, но там было много опечаток, так что я для себя в фоне подправил грамматику. Попробуйте переспросить Николаса, имел ли он в виду слитное написание.

Comment: @VladD даже если КМ считает что модераторы обязаны иметь общую точку зрения с администрацией и быть заодно с ней (что вы приравниваете к "против сообщества") - не факт, что модераторы считают так же. Хотелось бы понять, существует ли реальная проблема "модераторы против сообщества", о которой вы заявляете, или это чисто гипотетическая ситуация, которая, по вашему личному мнению может возникнуть. Вводить дополнительный бюрократический аппарат ради не существующей реально проблемы, и бороться против того, чего реально нет - напрасная трата времени и сил.

Comment: @PashaPash: В ситуациях «администрация против сообщества» за администрацию автоматически означает «против сообщества». И если мы выбираем модереторов, то хотелось бы, чтобы они хотя бы были обязаны придерживаться предвыборных обещаний. И если модератор считает, что он может быть против сообщества, которое его выбрало, зачем он тогда нужен? Дайте нам выбрать того, кто за нас.

Comment: @VladD ну вот давайте подождем, пока такая ситуация действительно возникнет, и посмотрим, за кого будут модераторы. а не будем чинить то, что не сломано.

Comment: @PashaPash: Уже была, как мне кажется.

Comment: @PashaPash:  Рум-овнеры, бан Qwertiy, навязывание бинайса и запрет на «пассивную агрессию» — во всех этих ситуациях администрация была против сообщества.

Comment: @VladD можно немного конкретики? действительно была ситуация, когда модераторы все как один встали против всего сообщества, за администрацию?

Comment: @PashaPash: Я пока фиксирую ситуации, в которых администрация была против сообщества. Николас в чате, как я понимаю, отрицал само наличие подобных ситуаций.

Comment: @VladD рум овнеры - решение владельцев сети, которое, к сожалению, модераторы оспорить не могут. тут модераторы ничем не ровнее обычных участников. Бан Qwertiy - обсуждался в мод чате, там больше недопонимания и "я не то имел ввиду", чем реального противостояния. То, что его так раздули, и почему его так раздули - это другой вопрос. Тем не менее, Qwertiy не сняли, и если вам интересна позиция других модераторов по поводу конфликта КМ и Qwertiy - спросите самого Qwertiy , на чьей стороне там был лично я. Запрет на агрессию и навязывание - хотелось бы конкретики, кому и что навязывают.

Comment: @PashaPash: Тем не менее, факт остаётся фактом: конфликты между администрацией и сообществом были. В нашем диалоге можно считать этот факт установленным? Поскольку в диалоге с Николасом я так и не смог заставить его с этим согласиться.

Comment: @VladD естественно, конфликты были. Но вы утверждаете, что модераторы в этих конфликтах всегда принимают сторону администрации, против сообщества. Хотя достаточно легко проверить, что это не так - просто посмотреть, что происходило при том же бане Qwertiy, и посмотреть на реальные действия по "навязыванию" - во всех последних конфликтах модераторы не становились все как один на сторону администрации.

Comment: @PashaPash: Хорошо, наличие конфликтов зафиксировано, с вами я продвинулся на шаг дальше. А можно ли каким-то образом рассказать, что было за дверями в конфликте вокруг Qwertiy? Меня и вправду волнует вопрос, с кем модераторы.

Comment: @VladD вы можете задать этот вопрос напрямую Qwertiy :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Это было бы не вполне этично с моей стороны по отношению к Qwertiy. Ну и всё же вы ведь говорите, что играете за нас, а не он.

Answer (score 9):

Я не знаю, как можно наесться впрок на месяц вперёд – и точно так же считаю утопичной попытку "раз и навсегда" решить проблемы. Поэтому возле заголовка темы на мой взгляд добавить год и месяц, чтобы зайдя в тему из будущего можно было сориентироваться к какому периоду относится топик.

Вообще же меня эти обсуждения проблем уже порядком поднадоели, потому что конструктивного в них становится всё меньше и меньше: все участвующие зафиксировали свои точки зрения и твёрдо стоят на своём, не слушая других. Думаете, подобная принципиальность похвальна? А теперь ответьте, продуктивна ли она для поиска общих точек соприкосновения и нахождения компромиссов? Я думаю, что непродуктивна.

Ну вот и имеем, что имеем: мы топчемся на одном месте и хоть по пять раз на день создавай подобные темы – ничего не изменится. Ну разве что будет приходить очередной новый участник, желающий помочь разрешить эту проблему, создаст очередную тему, ничего не выйдет и можно пойти на очередную итерацию вечного цикла.

Лично те проблемы, которые вижу я и которые уже озвучивал (я хочу, чтобы появилось ещё несколько русскоязычных сообществ на базе движка se) не решаются при текущем наборе ограничений в ресурсах. И как бы я не пытался заставить администрацию добровольно подписаться под эту задачу - ничего не получается, ибо с той стороны вполне себе реалисты сидят.

Ладно, с моими проблемами разобрались, но я хочу сказать немного о проблемах, которые озвучиваются некоторыми другими участниками. Я, мгм, имею смелость утверждать, что я довольно времени провёл слушая, о чём они говорят; понимаю и даже могу это объяснить в более понятной манере. (На самом деле нет, просто иногда помогает сказать то же самое, но другими словами - и шансы на то, что тебя поймут увеличиваются. Но это неточно.)

Но сначала несколько вводных слов на тему "кто имеет право говорить от имени <s>народа</s> сообщества".

Тут некоторым участникам уже отказали в праве говорить от имени сообщества.

Мол, один участник (два, сто, тысяча) не имеют права считать, что сказанное им является сказанным от лица сообщества. И этот отказ был расценён несколькими участниками как неуважение к их прошлым заслугам и вкладу в сообщество, который они до этого сделали.
А вам кстати не было бы обидно? Говорят, что самый главный вопрос для русских - это вопрос *уважения*, а тут выходит плюнули в самое святое.
Да собственно вопрос уважения очень сильно примешался ко всей этой истории, я потом ещё скажу об этом. Пока просто заметим в скобках: ты можешь хоть быть лидером рейтинга и одним из самых результативных метаписателей - ты никто, ты не имеешь говорить от лица сообщества, ты всего лишь yet another отвечающий по десктопу.

Давайте представим, что любой участник имеет право говорить только за себя (одна крайность, да ещё и имеет право с течением времени поменять свою точку зрения) или от лица всего сообщества (другая крайность). В ФИДО была в ходу такая поговорка как "отучаемся говорить за всех" и в этом было здравое зерно, но вот если очень хочется?

Чем можно аргументировать своё право говорить от лица всех. Я вижу следующие варианты, которые выглядят более-менее убедительно, а не просто "нет бога кроме народа и я пророк его":

- Можно апеллировать к большому вкладу в сообщество.
  У меня вот почти двести непрерывно проведённых дней на сайте/мете/чате и 10к+ репутации за ответы: я прочитал столько буковок, нацарапанных случайными участниками и завсегдатаями, что имею право считать, что слышал голос народа.
  Контраргумент: можно взять двух человек с одинаковой репутацией - и они почему-то слишком по-разному слышат народ.
- Можно апеллировать к выборам.
  На сайте 4200 участников, в выборах приняло участие 700 и за лично меня проголосовало 123 "моих" избирателя, которые доверили мне право в любых вопросах представлять их точку зрения.
  Контраргументы: я не слышал о том, чтобы у модераторов были общественные приёмные и никто из избранных не собирает явно фидбэк от своих избирателей. Кроме того, нет механизма отзыва модераторов - а значит, ничто не мешает избранному плевать на мнение избравших но оставаться при этом при должности любое время.
- Можно апеллировать к референдуму по конкретному вопросу.
  Референдумы ещё дороже, чем выборы человека - но гарантируют большую точность (даны по конкретной формулировке, имеют актуальность как минимум на дату голосования).
  Контраргументы: можно считать, что мнение толпы всегда коньюнктурно. Эксперт хочет хорошего, толпа просит хлеба и зрелищ.

Ну вот и как в таких условиях апеллировать к тому, что кто-то выступает от лица сообщества? PP верно говорит: никак. Но поскольку реальный вопрос был между строк об уважении <участника>, а не о имею право говорить от лица <множества участников>, то я знаю неплохой вариант смягчить это противоречие.
Нужно всего лишь уважительно относиться к каждому участнику, ибо уважая любого участника ты автоматически уважаешь всё сообщество.

Кстати, если вы хотите знать как автоматически уважать каждого участника - спросите у PashaPash, он знает. Нужно всего лишь установить а) единые б) гуманные в) правила.

Теперь собственно о проблемах, которые я слышал от некоторых других участников.

Один из них говорит об уважении. О том, что модераторы должны быть гуманными и заботиться о законопослушных участниках: принимать крупные решения  коллегиально, без вмешательства администрации, принимать их гласно, чтобы была возможность прозрачно проверить эти принципы. Ну попросту: текущие модераторы плохи, надо что-то с этим делать.
Не знаю, как оценивает всё остальное хе, сообщество эту проблему - но я бы поставил два к одному, что большинство не поддерживает. Вот прямо сейчас устрой референдум, то будет печально: 99% ничего не слышали, а те кто слышали считают, что и сам участник не очень достойно себя вёл (читай: не уважительно относился к общим правилам, считал свои личные правила выше общих)

Другой говорит о том, что нужно уважать участников, внесших большой вклад в развитие сообщества и давать часть прав, которые являются прерогативой хозяев сайта. Текущая модель, в которой администрация имеет право вето на любой вопрос (чтобы не угробить сообщество руками участников) его не устраивает ибо "недемократическая". Тут можно много говорить о добровольном взятии компанией на себя ограничений, но пока компания сама не захочет поделиться - можно только голосовать ногами в расчёте на то, что это побудит пересмотреть решение. Вариант "остаться и изнутри переубеждать, что есть варианты построить модель демократичнее" я оцениваю как малореальный: во-первых, модели никто не предложил, во-вторых, риск угробить сообщество непомерно велик и никто не знает, как его уменьшить, в-третих, компания является монополистом и пока никак не подпадает под регулятора (это вам не фейсбук, который заставили объяснять политику кампании -- более того, владелец сайта позволяет себе постить личное мнение о Трампе). Фактически речь идёт о варианте "дать некоторым участникам права community builder'ов", а таких людей днём с огнём не сыскать, особенно в виде бесплатных волонтёров.

Как-то так я себе вижу со стороны проблемы, которые озвучиваются. Надеюсь, кому-то мой взгляд поможет лучше понять их в моём пересказе.

Comment: «Пока просто заметим в скобках: ты можешь хоть быть лидером рейтинга и одним из самых результативных метаписателей - ты никто, ты не имеешь говорить от лица сообщества, ты всего лишь yet another отвечающий по десктопу.» — давайте не будем стыдливо прятаться за безличными предложениями.

Comment: Ну, справедливости ради, можно отметить, что есть механизм проявляющий рост "уважения/доверия" к пользователю в зависимости от вклада в сообщество - механизм привилегий.

Comment: У нас есть процедура отзыва модератора - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/. Ее может триггернуть любой мод, так что долго плевать на мнение избравших у одного конкретного модератора не получится.

Comment: Почему депутатская система является единственным решением, которое вы здесь обсуждаете? Как насчёт самых обыкновенных голосовалок, как в ВК, например, только на мете, и с выставлением определённого порога репутации, при котором человек может проголосовать, чтобы отделить общие вопросы, от судьбоносных?

Comment: @Diskyp: Не обязательно единственным. Если у вас есть идея, как можно сделать по-другому, предложите её!

Comment: @VladD мы, может, видим разные сообщения, но я именно так и сделал.

Comment: @Diskyp: И правда, простите за необоснованную претензию! Я вижу ваш ответ, да. Но я имел в виду предложение о другом методе голосования.

Comment: Попробуйте пожалуйста сформулировать TLDR в шапке ответа. Это поможет структурировать ответы на вопрос ТС.

Answer (score 9):

Я опоздал, но всё же выскажусь.

> Зачем Вы здесь, что привлекает Вас в сообществе?

Когда-то я давал [длинный список причин, почему я на РуСО](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318). Как интепретировать зачёркивание — вам виднее. Скажу только, что в моей помощи с систематизацией сайт больше не нуждается, живое общение переехало, а все остальные забавы помножаются на ноль тем, что администрация видит во мне врага (это в какой-то мере и на моей совести, но сути не меняет).

Так что корректнее было бы ответить, что РуСО привлекает меня как инструмент получения ответа на вопросы, которые по тем или иным причинам не имели успеха на большом СО.

> В чём Вы видите основные проблемы сообщества на текущий момент?

Нет предмета обсуждения: нет сообщества. Для меня сообщество — это та группка активных пользователей, которые впереди всех в сложных вопроса и ответах, которые лезут на Мету высказывать мнение, которые сидят в чате и обсуждают животрепещущие вопросы, которые живут сайтом, для которых сайт действительно что-то значит и которые хотят сделать его лучше.

Вот это всё я больше не вижу.

Чат мёртв. Чат умер не просто так, это результат планомерных действий администрации, которая запрещает высказывание альтернативных мнений. Администрация может сколько угодно упираться и говорить, что это во благо, но когда половина участников или улетала в бан, или теряла сообщения, или лишалась прав, а остальная половина это всё постоянно наблюдала, то не надо ожидать, что в чате захотят оставаться, какие бы "добрые намерения" ни объявлялись целью.

Модераторы, которых избирало сообщество из своих же самых активных представителей, поделились строго на два лагеря: (1) "админ всегда прав" и (2) "моя хата с краю". Один модератор что-то там попытался высказать поперёк, но его насильно засунули во вторую категорию. Уж не знаю, может, где-то там в закрытых модераторских чатах и процветает свобода слова, только сообщество об этом никак не может узнать: ни напрямую, ни косвенно. Нет никаких внешних признаков.

> Что, по Вашему, неправильно в поведении/действиях управляющего/модераторов?

Руководство компании выбрало конкретный путь развития, который умерщвляет сообщество во имя эффективности и траффика. КМ, осознавая это или нет (не имеет значения), принимает решения, которые развивают сайт в соответствии с заданным вектором. Модераторы, хоть и избраны сообществом, фактически не имеют права перечить установке сверху (это стандартный вопрос модератору на выборах, и правильный ответ — "нет, не имею права, буду молчать в тряпочку").

В итоге все поступили правильно. А сообщество — тю-тю. Но нужно ли оно? Кого и зачем спасаем-то? Нам же сказали, что оно ненужное. Всё официально.

Когда-то был Хэшкод. Он был ламповым, там все друг друга знали и ценили, там можно было обсуждать любые вопросы. На его место пришёл РуСО, который обрезал ламповость и ограничил тематики вопросов. Старое сообщество отвалилось в силу несовместимости с новыми правилами, но возникло новое, которое хотело превратить Хэшкод в образцовый сайт сети SE. Теперь пришла его очередь уходить. Ничего личного, только бизнес.

> Что и кому следует предпринять, чтобы это исправить?

Руководство компании двигается в этом направлении многие годы. На разных подсайтах это происходило с разной скоростью. Просто сейчас лягушка сварилась.

Что-то может измениться, если руководство вдруг поменяет мнение. Этого не произошло за 10 лет, поэтому не произойдёт сейчас из-за горстки отщепенцев на локальном сайтике.

Надо понять и принять, что теперь "сообщество" РуСО — это механические отвечаторы на вопросы без права мнения. Если кому-то это не нравится, то надо просто сделать выводы. Я сделал.

> Верите ли Вы, что сообщество в состоянии преодолеть эти проблемы?

Оно преодолеет. Оно изменится. Но уже без нас.

Comment: `Но это будет уже совсем другая история ©` Грустно...

Comment: Времена меняются. Приоритеты компании меняются. Сообщество больше не нужно, упор на "привлечение трафика". Это не только на SO ориентир на трафик, а не на качество. На многих ресурсах тоже самое. Тот же хабр, dtf и т.п.

Comment: @Suvitruf Ориентиры могут быть схожими (мы все живём не в сказке, а в реальном мире, которым правят деньги), вопрос с масштабах и моральных принципах. Денискин, сколько бы бочку на него ни катили, не только хочет фармить бабло на траффике, но и понимает ценность сообщества. Да, он идёт на непопулярные компромиссы, но у него хватает смелости публично признавать ошибки и идти на обсуждение. Да, "Хабр не торт", да, я презираю некоторые его правила и технические решения, но сайт до сих пор жив, до сих пор лучший в категории, и его сообщество состоит не только из редакторов на окладе.

Comment: @Athari а толку от того, что Денискин ошибки признаёт? Это, конечно, мило, но своими извинениями он хабр уже не вернёт. В 2011 там были почти одни технические статьи, обсуждения, сейчас одни копроблоги/реклама/всякая фигня от платных редакторов вроде маркса и ализара.

Comment: @Suvitruf Вы приписываете действиям администрации слишком много чести в вопросе "обнетортивания" Хабра. Интернет изменился, люди изменились. Вы не можете ни сохранить, ни вернуть ни старый Хабр, ни старые форумы, ни старый ФИДО.

Comment: Вы могли бы составить свое TLDR и добавить его в шапку ответа? Это упростит ориентирование в ответах. Спасибо

Comment: @Kromster У моего ответа нет и не будет TL;DR, он никогда не станет пунктиком в списке "конструктивных предложений", потому что он отвергает предлагаемую в вопросе конструкцию "что не так, и как это починить". Ориентироваться в этом ответе не надо, он абсолютно бесполезный.

Comment: TLDR написать можно ко всему, но раз не хотите, то дело ваше

Comment: @Kromster TL;DR моего ответа — это "наше время ушло", а совсем не то, что вы написали.

Comment: Ну так можно TLDR к вашему ответу написать или нет? И если да - то напишите плиз. (хотя ваш тезис про то что время ушло, недоказан, и его вполне можно было бы обосновать и эти обоснования разместить в качестве ответа на вопрос ТС)

Comment: @Kromster Если кто-то хочет разобраться в происходящем, то чтение однострочных заголовков не поможет, нужно читать весь текст от и до, поэтому всякого рода обобщающие заголовки я считаю бессмысленными, и уж тем более на моём ответе, который не содержит конструктивной позиции, так что я предпочту сохранить его в первозданном виде. Кто хочет TL;DR — может мой ответ не читать.

Comment: Я обычно читаю как минимум жанр фильма и смотрю постер с актерами, перед тем как начинать его смотреть. У книг тоже обычно есть мини-содержание К длинным ответам отношение примерно такое же. Хорошо, я вашу позицию понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

**Слишком свободная интерпретация правил**

Проблема, для которой я пока не вижу удовлетворительного решения — это слишком свободная интерпретация правил, и расхождения в ней между разными частями сообщества, а также, традиционно, между сообществом и администрацией.
Проблема осложняется ещё и относительным произволом в выборе точного значения при переводе с английского, а также тем, что игра слов или двойное значение слова может сойти за толкование правила.

Пример такого: термин «агрессия». Никто не спорит с тем, что агрессия в её общечеловеческом понимании — угрозы, шантаж, запугивание — недопустимы у нас на сайте. Но если трактовать агрессию расширительно, то под зонтичный термин «агрессия» может подойти и ирония, потому что кто-то может не понимать юмора и на неё обидеться. Или можно натянуть на «агрессию» новомодную кальку с английского «пассивная агрессия», которая просто означает молчаливое несогласие.

Если допускать такое вольное расширение понятий, то любая невыхолощенная коммуникация грозит стать запрещённой.

Аналогично, есть проблема свободной интерпретации того, что считать обидным, а что нет. Если мы ослабим критерии, мы можем допустить оскорбления участников. Если мы усилим критерии, любой участник может объявить любое слово обидным, и тем самым исключить его из нашего лексикона.

Обычные методы решения этой проблемы — полагаться на здравый смысл администрации — к сожалению, не всегда срабатывают как надо, примеры чего мы видели не так давно.

---

**Предложение по решению**

В такой ситуации имеет смысл дать право участникам, считающим, что администрация неверно оценивает претензию, право на *арбитраж*: пост на Мете с изложением проблемы и упоминание конкретных лиц (если они на то согласны), и пусть решение принимается голосованием неравнодушных участников. При этом каждый, как пострадавшая сторона, так и администрация, будут иметь право на свободное изложение своей позиции.

Если участники посчитают вопрос слишком мелочным, чтобы быть вынесенным на Мету и привлечь из внимание, пускай голосуют минусами.

Такой демократический элемент, думаю, был бы хорош и уместен.

Answer (score 2):

Инициатива (вопрос) — отличная и полезная идея. Ранее данная инициатива существовала на сайте в несколько ином формате — формы отзывов Google Forms, а сам опрос проходил под новый год. Я благодарен участникам, которые решились публично поделится с сообществом своими чувствами, которые они испытывают взаимодействия на платформе. Субъективные отзывы, основанные на личном опыте, очень важны для компании и для сообщества.

Я крайне рад, что данный вопрос — это инициатива самих участников сообщества. Ваши переживания и беспокойства совершенно оправданы.

Со своей стороны я бы тоже хотел присоединиться к отзывам и поделиться своим субъективными переживаниями. Я попробую раскрыть несколько проблем, которые вижу лично я (то есть это моя позиция, которая может отличаться от позиции компании–разработчика, я говорю за себя).

> ### Зачем Вы здесь, что привлекает Вас в сообществе?

Причина моего участия на сайте та же, что и раньше — я считаю, что было бы здорово иметь сайт для профессиональных разработчиков на русском языке, так как русскоязычному человеку удобнее понимать и изъясняться на родном языке, тем более на такую сложную тему как программирование. Мне дороги настоящие и будущие русскоязычные разработчики, их судьба. На мой взгляд, Stack Overflow на русском уравнивает шансы русскоязычных разработчиков закрепиться в глобальном мире информационных технологий, делая профессиональные знания доступными, развернутыми и своевременными.

Выражаясь образно — я очень хочу видеть на улицах разработчиков самоуправляемых такси, а не обучавшихся на разработчиков водителей такси.

> ### В чём Вы видите основные проблемы сообщества на текущий момент?

#### 1. Модерация управляющим

Прямо сейчас эта проблема уже практически [решена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/6), но упомянуть о ней стоит. Ранее управляющий активно участвовал в модерации сообщества. Я вижу следующие проблемы как результат такого подхода:

- Действия управляющего приписываются всей команде модераторов.
- Решения принимаются одним человеком.

Сообществу у нас дружное, большое, с прекрасными модераторами, которые разбираются в жизни сообщества куда лучше, чем управляющий. Уверен, что в будущем участие управляющего в модерировании будет очень редким исключением.

#### 2. Сегрегация «мы» и «вы»

Последнее время можно было наблюдать группу людей, которая обозначала себя как «мы» и пыталась противостоять, бороться против «их» (то есть нас). Абсурд дошел до того, что внутри этой группы участники стали называть себя не просто участниками одного сообщества, а, цитирую, «союзниками», у них не фигурирует задачи разобраться в проблеме и прийти к оптимальному решению, а, цитирую «не отступиться от своих союзников». Как минимум, в рамках этого сайта данная идея не имеет вообще никакого смысла и навязана почитателями милитаризма.

Stack Overflow создается разработчиками для разработчиков, безотносительно каких–то предрассудков. *На сайте есть только мы*. Каждый из нас играет свою важную роль: кто–то отвечает на вопросы по C#, кто–то задает по Python, кто–то проявляет заботу о участниках в роли модератора. В то же время, у всех нас одна цель, единая миссия — собрать сводную базу знаний по программированию.

В процессе совместной работы, могут появляются моменты, требующие [коллективного рассмотрения и принятия решения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6), но не один из них не может является поводом для сегрегации. Давайте остановимся и посмотрим, нет ли некоего катализатора, который «способствовал» столь сильной поляризации людей, которые собрались на сайте с добрыми намерениями — помочь коллегами, поделиться с ними своими знаниями. Возможно, все спорные моменты вовсе не разногласия, а общие для всех нас проблемы, решить которые хочет каждый.

#### 3. Непринятие чужих ошибок

Несколько последних месяцев некоторые участники грубо высказываются про ошибки других (иногда это переходило в откровенные издевательства над личностью допустившего ошибку). Мне кажется это большой проблемой, потому что ошибка — это часть процесса. Не ошибается только тот, кто ничего не делает.

Хотелось бы в этой связи заметить, что «указания на ошибку» и «оскорбления» совершенно разные вещи. Указание на ошибку включает в себя совместное обсуждение *вероятной* проблемы (возможно, вы просто неверно поняли что–то) и последующие совместные поиски оптимального решения. Вылитый на кого–то негатив никому не нужен и замечаниями не является.

Видите ошибку? Расскажите о ней в вежливой дружеской беседе. Убедитесь, что собеседник понял *и принял* ваше замечание, постарайтесь найти обоюдно полезное решение.

#### 4. Абстрактные абстракции

Проблема обсуждения абстрактных абстракций в неверных предположениях и умозаключениях на разных этапах обсуждений, которые в подавляющем большинстве случаев невозможно распознать отличить от верных, пока не попробуешь (то есть на практике будет доказано обратное). Результаты таких обсуждений с завидной регулярностью неверны, но где именно — не ясно.

Абстрактной проблеме можно предложить только абстрактное решение, которое будет у каждого свое. Если есть конкретная проблема, к ней всегда можно найти конкретное решение, с которым согласится большинство.

#### 5. Непонимание роли управляющего и модераторов в жизни сайта

Внутри компании мы придерживаемся подхода «[servant leadership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_leadership)». Этот же подход мы применяем в сообществах.

Согласно данному подходу, в первую очередь рассматриваются нужды людей, занятых в непосредственном создании продукта. Задача руководителей — обеспечить подчиненных всем необходимым для успешного решения их производственных задач. Другими словами, руководитель в общении с сотрудником задает вопрос «что я могу для вас сделать», вместо стандартной «сделайте для меня это».

В контексте этого подхода, модераторы выступают опорой и поддержкой участников сообщества. Их задача — сделать так, чтобы сайтом было приятно пользоваться, чтобы участники хотели быть частичкой сообщества. Управляющий выступает опорой и поддержкой для модераторов. Его задача — сделать так, чтобы у модераторов были все необходимы инструменты и права для эффективного управления сообществом, чтобы модераторам нравилось быть модераторами этого сообщества.

Управляющий и модераторы нужны на сайте, чтобы помогать сообществу в решении проблем. И я бы хотел задать два вопроса:

1. Что я, как управляющий, могу сделать для вас, уважаемые участники и модераторы?
2. Что модераторы могут сделать для вас, участники?

**Дополнение**

Хочу образно пояснить то, как я понимаю модель «servant leadership» в контексте сайта. Понятие сложное, может быть воспринято неверно.

*Что НЕ является «servant leadership», в моем понимании*

Представьте, что наш сайт — это ресторан. Как может показаться из названия, задача «управляющего заведением» обслужить посетителей в роли раболепящего  официанта. То есть заходит посетитель, разваливается на стуле и кричит — «Эй, мальчик, поди ко мне, да побыстрее!», а после обеда стучит кулаком требуя владельца заведения к нему на поклон, чтобы он выслушал все замечания по интерьеру, меню, еде, а также дал документ с обязательствами все эти замечания исправить.

На этом сайте такого нет и никогда не будет. Если кто–то заходит, «бросается» в сотрудников «хотелками» и ждет, когда ему отчитаются о реализации, то ждать придется долго.

*Что похоже на «servant leadership», в моем понимании*

Если опять же говорить о кафе, то наш сайт я бы представил как заведение, которое ближе по смыслу к смеси [антикафе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5) и [шведского стола](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB). Основные идеи:

- Заведение открыто для всех.
- Еду приносят сами посетители и выкладывают ее на общий стол.
- Каждый, даже тот, кто пришел ни с чем, может угоститься чем хочет совершенно бесплатно.
- Никаких официантов.
- Наиболее инициативные и ответственные посетители стоят на раздаче и регулируют систему так, чтобы всем всего хватило, а также, чтобы все вели себя подобающим образом и не мешали остальным.
- Управляющий заведением отвечает за интерьер, чистоту, за правила поведения в заведение, за общую безопасность и комфорт.
- Управляющий все время находится в зале. Любой желающий может подойти и в вежливой форме указать на недостатки или высказать пожелания.
- Управляющий, на основе пожеланий и имеющихся ресурсах, договаривается с владельцем заведения о необходимых улучшениях. Перед улучшением выбранные инициативы вывешиваются при входе на стенде, где каждый желающий может оставить свой отзыв о них.
- Поскольку ресурсы заведения обладают свойством конечности, реализацию получают только те предложения, которые как–либо делают жизнь посетителей лучше, приятнее, позволяют пользоваться заведением эффективнее.
- Реализация любого пожелания проходит только совместно с автором предложения, после совместного детального рассмотрения всех аспектов. Если автор (или другой посетитель, разделяющий ту же идею) не готов к диалогу и совместной работе, то инициатива может быть снята с рассмотрения.

Как вы можете видеть, выбранный нами подход несколько сложен, но мы верим, что следуя ему мы «накормим больше людей».

> ### Что и кому следует предпринять, чтобы это исправить?

Ключевой особенностью нашего сообщества я считаю то, что здесь ответственен каждый. И поэтому сдвинуться с места мы сможем только если все вместе будем двигаться в направлении решения проблем, которые нас волнуют.

И этот вопрос именно об этом!

> ### Что вам нравится в сообществе?

<sub>На мой взгляд, это вопрос, которого недостает в исходном списке.</sub>

Спешу выделить:

- Наше сообщество очень дружное, участники доверяют друг другу и готовы к самораскрытию.
- В сообществе высокий уровень вовлечения, все участники беспокоятся за сообщество и его будущее.
- Культура общения сообщества на высочайшем уровне, мы умеем конструктивно обсуждать самые сложные проблемы организации без придирок и личных выпадов.

И да, у нас лучший в мире движок для накопления базы знаний!

Если бы меня попросили охарактеризовать сообщество одним словом, вероятно, я бы использовал «сострадание», потому что нам, очевидно, не безразличны наши коллеги, мы хотим помогать им, расти вместе с ними.

Подскажите, какие положительные стороны в сообществе видите вы? Какое одно слово вы бы использовали, чтобы описать сообщество?

---

Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы собранные в этом вопросе ответы вылились в нечто больше, чтобы идеи участников были услышаны и рассмотрены и самим сообществом, и компанией–разработчиком. Давайте вместе приложим для этого все силы! Например, будем активнее задавать вопросы авторам ответов о конкретных предлагаемых шагах решения видимых ими проблем, а по результатам обсуждений подготовим какой–то обзор, которым можно будет поделиться с другими международными сообществами и далее, с компанией–разработчиком.

Comment: "не отступиться от своих союзников". Если это цитата, хотелось бы знать первоисточник.

Comment: Обсуждение абстракций возникает обычно из-за того, что на Мете запрещено указание конкретных личностей и их конкретных действий. Отмените это правило, и проблема абстракций немедленно исчезнет.

Comment: @VladD На мой взгляд, где–то закралось недопонимание. Мы обоими руками за рассмотрения конкретных действий — «[Постановка вопроса в обобщённом виде побуждает сообщество обсуждать проблему нейтрально, что помогает сообществу сфокусироваться на самой проблеме и снимает стресс с участника, чьё поведение породило дискуссию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6)». Обобщенно, но не абстрактно.  Мы просим сконцентрироваться на конкретной проблеме, без ругани конкретных людей.

Comment: Если вы поняли этот ответ иначе, пожалуйста, укажите на места, где его следует подправить?

Comment: На проблему уже неоднократно указывал вам и я, и, например, [@Athari в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46084058#46084058). Мой пойнт в том, что если не указывать конкретных лиц и действий, то любой может возразить «такого не было». И это не теоретическая _абстрактная_ возможность, а реально использовавшаяся отмазка. Спросите у того же @Athari.

Comment: А можно ещё пояснить, что такое «абстрактные абстракции»? И какие ещё абстракции бывают? И желательно, несколько примеров этого, а то мне без этого кажется, что такого у нас никогда не было. (Да, это сарказм.)

Comment: @VladD Обобщенный пример написать действительно сложнее, чем описать свое субъективное мнение о участнике. В этом я с вами согласен. Но игра стоит свеч, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @VladD Абстрактная абстракция — это некая абстрактная проблема, рассматриваемая в контексте абстрактной системы, которая, вроде бы как–то похожа на упрощенную абстракцию настоящей системы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: В первый раз встречаю такой термин. Ну да ладно. Но поскольку вы требуете не упоминать конкретные проблемы с конкретными людьми, то вы сами требуете эти самые «абстрагированные абстрактные абстракции». Так что проблема в вашем требовании.

Comment: @VladD В вопросе предложение не ссылаться на людей. Конечно же, мы ЗА конкретные проблемы. Я об этом и пишу в этом ответе, что надо рассматривать конкретные проблемы. Возможно не лучший, но все же [пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6759/6), что я имею в виду.

Answer (score 2):

**Несоответствие ожиданий участников <s>со времен ХэшКода</s> и фактических возможностей предоставляемых платформой SE**

*Ответ составлен из анализа общения с разными участниками*

SE выстроен вокруг вопросов и ответов. На тех масштабах, которых достиг SE, участники, которые их генерируют - по большому счету расходный материал. Сегодня пишут одни, завтра придут другие и точно так же продолжат писать. Все старые ответы никуда не пропадают, остаются на SE навечно. В то же время, на небольшом ХэшКоде, участники имели куда больший вес и влияние на площадку. Теперь же, и участники - винтики (по факту идеологии SE), да и сам ruSO всего лишь винтик в большом семействе сайтов SE. Незаменимых, на нашем с вами уровне, к сожалению, - нет. Реальных рычагов влияния - тоже.

Проблема в том, что SO уже давно сформировался и закостенел. Формула его "успеха" давно зафиксирована. По этой формуле, SO всех уравнивает и выдает достаточно ограниченный список прав/привилегий высокореповым участникам (даже 20к+ не имеют каких-то особых привилегий или возможности влиять на правила сайта). Владельцы платформы лишь допиливают новые фичи оглядываясь на enSO и свои видения.

Соглашаться на участие в такой платформе или нет - личное дело каждого. Многие согласны, т.к. с одной стороны, в начале участия в SE/SO вопросов о привилегиях не возникает, а с ростом - привыкаешь принимать условия такими, какие они есть (и они, кстати, достаточно неплохи, сами по себе). Кому-то просто по душе формат SO с его чистыми вопросами и ответами и уважительным отношением.

Вероятно, проблема части участников ruSO в том, что они не сами выросли в этих условиях, а были "импортированы" из ХэшКода (и рунета). Условно говоря, пришли в деревню из мегаполиса и сказали - "а теперь вы будете жить по нашим правилам". Во многом правила хорошие, но непривычные простым жителям. Почему-то теперь плевать мимо урны плохо (урны ещё какие-то придумали ... в деревне такого не было отродясь). Естественно, это вызывает разочарование и желание бунта - как так, "нашу свободу и самобытность отнимают". Недавно "спущенный" сверху "бинайс" очень сильно обнажил эту проблему.

Можно попробовать сформулировать проблему другими словами - сообщество ruSO недостаточно "взрослое/зрелое" для SE. Если бы ХК рос и развивался как SO, на протяжении 10 лет и привлек бы миллионную аудиторию, проблемы возникли бы те же, но были бы более растянуты во времени. Уверен, что и SO сталкивался с тем же, что роль участников снижалась, по мере роста размера сайта.

Comment: Это возможно починить без замены состава сообщества?

Comment: @vp_arth починить можно все, причем с разных сторон. Можно ruSO починить, выбив суверинитет, можно участников "починить" (кнутом или пряником). Вопрос о "стоимости" и целесообразности. Мне могут импонировать одни варианты, другим - другие.

Comment: Для справки: среди взбунтовавшихся "союзников" © не так много народа, реально заставшего ранний ХэшКод. Старичкам того ХэшКода дали пендаля несколько раньше, ещё при переезде на движок SO (см. траекторию полёта Бармалея). Вы наблюдаете пендаль другому сообществу, в большой мере сформировавшемуся уже на SO. @VladD — скорее исключение, потому что застал все поколения. / *Все старые ответы никуда не пропадают, остаются на SE навечно* — не совсем верно. База ХэшКода была значительно вычищена. То же самое в своё время происходило на большом SO. (Да, всё остаётся на Data.SE, но кто ж там читает.)

Comment: @Athari ценное замечание, спасибо!

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил в конце "роль **отдельно взятых** участников".

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь нахватать минусов, но раз просили высказаться...

> Зачем Вы здесь, что привлекает Вас в сообществе?

Я здесь, наверное и как многие другие, для того, чтоб поделиться тем небольшим опытом, который имею и перенять опыт, который имеют знающие люди. В сообществе ничего не привлекает, ровно как и не отталкивает, так как нет у меня никакого опыта с сообществом.

> В чём Вы видите основные проблемы сообщества на текущий момент?

Я лишь случайно и как бы это ни парадоксально звучало, внезапно узнал о имеющихся противоречиях, банах, и прочих далеко не приятных моментах. Для меня также было неожиданностью, что на техническом ресурсе нашлось место и возможность для оскорблений, инсинуаций и взаимных упрёков. Для меня ресурс в первую очередь является площадкой, с помощью которой я накапливаю свой профессиональный опыт и по мере знаний и возможностей, стараюсь помочь начинающим, вспоминая себя на их месте. Поэтому я не могу в полной мере ни понять, ни осознать все проблемы, которые здесь описываются, так как не сталкивался ни с чем подобным. Но с одной проблемой в последнее время сталкиваюсь: вопросы по .Net остаются без ответа.

> Что, по Вашему, неправильно в поведении/действиях управляющего/модераторов?

Не имел до сих пор никаких спорных моментов с модераторами, дай Бог дальше так и будет, но на мой взгляд, как и любая власть, абсолютная власть, т.е. без апелляционная - развращает. Если имеется возможность опротестовать действия модераторов, то, скорее всего, проблем возникнуть не должно (не знаю только как сейчас обстоят дела со ссылками на удалённые сообщения и комментарии, которые необходимо предоставить при опротестовании).

> Что и кому следует предпринять, чтобы это исправить?

Никаких архисложных усилий, на мой взгляд, предпринимать не нужно. Каждый должен заниматься своим делом. Если я могу помочь кому-то, то конечно помогу, без хамства и подколов. Если модераторы будут не предвзято и справедливо принимать решения, то и вопросов не должно к ним возникать. Владельцы ресурса будут и дальше его развивать, ведь это в их интересах в конце концов. А если мы, то есть "все", будем вдаваться в неконструктивные дискуссии, критиковать не предлагая решений, то это будет как, извините за моветон, "каждый суслик в поле агроном".

> Верите ли Вы, что сообщество в состоянии преодолеть эти проблемы?

Вера ничего здесь не решает. Либо преодолеет - и всё "гут", либо нет - тогда и ресурса нет.

Answer (score -2):

У вас одна большая проблема, вы не хотите прислушиваться к пользователям ресурса. 
Вы готовы заминусовать любую мысль, которая противоречит правилам, которые вы считаете непоколебимыми.

Я уверен что подавляющее большинство, которое можно назвать администрацией на этом ресурсе - навряд ли старше 27 лет. Я же вам могу сказать что 15 лет назад проблемы, например на форумах, были ровно теми же что и сейчас. Однако кто то выносит пользу из опыта, а кто то нет.

Ваша проблема в том что успех для вас, как для представляющих администрацию - это минимум критики в ваш адрес. Однако настоящий успех заключается в том, чтоб ресурс был удобен и приятен как желторотому студенту, которые делает первые шаги в том ремесле, которое он выбрал (специально или случайно), так и старым пердунам, которые решили наконец через ресурс передать свои знания или хотя бы простые ответы, которые подтолкнуть молодежь к дальнейшим личным подвигам. Администрация, однако, действует по лекалам - лишь бы чего не вышло.  Уже давно пора понять что "лишь бы чего не вышло" это задача искусственного интеллекта, но ваша задача - "главное чтоб все получилось"!

Вы можете посмотреть вашу проблему даже в этом топе, особенно присмотритесь к тем сообщениям которые нещадно заминусовали за критику. Это наиболее ценные ответы вам , тем кто хочет ресурс сделать лучше. Однако вы делаете вид что вам интересно чужое мнение. 
Возьмем например ответ пользователя @Diskyp . За коим бесом он был заминусован ? Он ведь попросту высказал свое мнение и в идее данного поста к нему стоило бы прислушаться, однако тут же моралисты бросились его осуждать и доказывать что он не прав. Да какого беса он не прав ? Он ведь попросту высказал мысль. Прямо скажем ту же мысль что высказал вчера я и получил тоже тонну критики от моралистов. Но мы понимаем кто эти моралисты и не обижаемся на них лично, однако обидно за ресурс, который попросту останется без "звезд", а будут только "правильные" - которые вовремя расставляют запятые.

Ваша проблема в том что у вас много деревянных. Это не оскорбление, это попытка описать людей, которым ты пытаешься что то объяснить, но их это не волнует. Их волнует только то что вдоль или поперек, главное чтоб "лишь бы ничего не случилось".

На этом я пожалуй пока что остановлюсь. Спасибо что хотели узнать мое мнение.

Comment: Вы, мне кажется, всё ещё не поняли, что SO - это не ваш личный блог, здесь есть свои правила и порядки. Если вам что-то не нравится, вы можете создать вопрос на мете и обсудить проблему. А ответ @Diskyp'а заминусовали, скорей всего, потому что он больше про личные обиды и слабо вяжется с сабжем в целом.

Answer (score -3):

**Слишком мягкая политика в отношении людей, которые явно не удосужились ознакомиться с правилами, пишут откровенный треш в виде вопросов и так далее**

> В чём Вы видите основные проблемы сообщества на текущий момент?

Не хочу вдаваться в долгие демагогии, разбираться в тонкостях текущих конфликтов с администрацией, ведь поднятые темы хоть и «остры», однако, как по мне, лишь частично пересекаются с основной(-ыми) проблемой, которую я вижу.

Где-то проскакивала фраза от одного из участников, что в сообществе (я считаю, конкретно в ruSO) перебарщивают с бинайсом <sub><sub>*(именно так, любителей править это слово прошу воздержаться)*</sub></sub>. Даже кто-то написал, что целями руководства является не развитие сообщества в его лучшем виде, а «нагон трафика», чтобы как можно больше новых людей с любым качеством ответов/вопросов приходило, росли циферки и всё такое прочее. *(не гарантирую точность цитаты и ссылкой не пруфану, да и стёрли скорее всего)*

Что я бы хотел сюда добавить? Я немного разделяю это мнение, а возможно даже выдул его из пальца, увидев какую-то безобидную фразу.

Если говорить конкретно, то я считаю, что стоило бы в некоторых вопросах давать возможность чуть более жёстко отвечать/комментировать людям, которые явно не удосужились ознакомиться с правилами, пишут откровенный треш в виде вопросов и так далее.

Я уже писал где-то ответ о том, что отправлять в гугл с вежливым комментарием это вполне неплохо и адекватный и перспективный разработчик от этого получит даже больше пользы, однако меня заминусили ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

В чём это конкретно выражается? В том, что, например, плюс-минус один и тот же вопрос, который задан на enSO и у нас, будет у них заминусован в течение 30 секунд, а у нас получит 1-2 плюса, и ещё ответ получит 3-5 плюсов, а то и больше, при том что проблема решается одним запросом в гугл и копипастой с enSO из вопроса семилетней давности.

Я не утрирую, добавлю несколько ссылок в виде пруфов, конкретно из числа моих ответов — и я удивлён, что реакция сообщества именно такая. Даже я удивлён именно реакции на ответы, абсолютная примитивщина (как я уже упомянул, в том числе от моего имени) вызывает «бурную» реакцию, при том что иногда хорошие вопросы не получают ни галочки, но даже одного плюса.

Всегда же шёл разговор о том, что мы пополняем базу знаний, польза для «других поколений» и всё такоее прочее. Но какая объективная польза, например, от [такого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861307/string-null-%D0%B8)? Да, он получил минуса. А первый же принятый ответ в 2 строчки текста получает `+6`. Причём сложность вопроса и ответа даже до уровня детского сада не доходят.

Другие ссылки: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857497/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-notification/857501#857501) (за что `+1` вопросу? за что `+5` ответу? вопрос вообще можно закрыть как опечатку, потому что автор даже не удосужился прочитать стактрейс ошибки, и продолжает постить подобные вопросы, хотя, я гарантирую, после пары таких на enSO он бы уже получил бан на вопросы), [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817256/%D0%AD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/817258#817258) (без комментариев, два плюса на вопрос и `+5` на ответ в две строчки, да быстрее было в IDE по автодополнению среди 1000 методов найти нужный, чем идти на SO и спрашивать), [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817180/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5/817183#817183) (`+8` карл! сколько, уже года три прошло с релиза Android M? на поиск информации об этом даже 30 секунд потратить не нужно, да и мало кто не знает о необходимости запроса разрешений, — а сам ответ это 80% просто скопипащенного кода с доки по андроиду), [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813102/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-4-4-2/813104#813104) (один плюс да вопрос получил, а за что ответу `+5`, если там 80% символов это копипаст стактрейса из вопроса? почему вопрос не получил `-10`?), [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861651/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-js), и так можно без конца продолжать.

Возможно, где-то я переброщил, где-то утрирую, но совсем закрывать глаза, я считаю, тоже не стоит. Было бы неплохо сделать упор на качество, а не на количество. Да, ruSO не может себе позволить каждого второго банить на вопросы и вообще разбрасываться аудиторией, как например enSO, однако компромисс можно найти, если хотя бы начать думать в эту сторону.

> Верите ли Вы, что сообщество в состоянии преодолеть эти проблемы?

Тезис формулируется довольно просто — не стоит вдаваться в крайности, навязывать чрезмерный бинайс, думать что любое не «рукоцеловательное» общение это всё, переход границ. Не нужно разделять всё на «содомию, троллинг, унижение» и то что есть сейчас и «*вы что хотите как в/на другом месте?*». На том же enSO вполне можно кинуть ссылку на `idownvotedbecau.se` или даже в гугл без комментария, и много чего ещё можно, что я бы не советовал перенимать нам, однако, опять же, надо помнить о компромиссах.

Я верю, что проблему можно решить, если признать её существование. Если чуть более критично относиться к появляющемуся контенту, более-менее обходительно указывать на ошибки, а не давать готовое решение, даже если оно в 2 строчки кода пишется, либо давать с подробным объяснением, кидать ссылку с точной формулировкой в гугл, довнвотидь и голосовать за закрытие, то в том числе и авторитет сайта вырастет. Те, кто пришел сюда задать один вопрос «и умереть», всё равно не вернутся. Остальные хотя бы станут чуть больше задумываться.

Что может быть в итоге? Некачественного контента станет поменьше, пользы для этих же начинающих разработчиков будет больше (имхо), авторитет сайта возрастёт (хотя бы у опытных разработчиков). Все в выигрыше.

Потому что, далеко не секрет, (хотя, может это только у меня так?) если спросить любого более-менее опытного разработчика насчёт ruSO, он не скажет ничего кроме «ой да забей, кто на русском пишет/спрашивает/ищет ответы? что, ruSO? не смеши, ты видел что там вообще задают и на что отвечают, о какой пользе речь?» — и поспорить с этим, я считаю, трудно. И это может быть немного обидно.

Comment: Насчёт "один и тот же вопрос, который задан на enSO и у нас, будет у них заминусован в течение 30 секунд, а у нас получит 1-2 плюса, и ещё ответ получит 3-5 плюсов". А вы понимаете, что у нас с enso разный уровень заполненности базы? У нас по большинству вопросов нет ещё ответов, чтобы минусовать "да сколько же можно одно и то же спрашивать???". И у нас разная степень развития сообществ в том смысле, что у нас ещё сообщество только начинает развиваться, а у них уже весьма зрелое. У нас может людей и много, но это спрашивающие, а не отвечающие.

Comment: @AK я сделал поправку на это и упомянул, что модель поведения на enSO — не панацея. Но я также указал конкретные случаи и что в них не так. `недостаточный уровень заполнения базы` — если она плохо заполнена, то её стоит заполнять (пусть громко не прозвучит) мусором? Упор должен быть не на количество, а на качество, как я и упомянул — и касается это в первую очередь спрашивающих.

Comment: *проблема решается одним запросом в гугл и копипастой с enSO из вопроса семилетней давности* — ну и что, зато у нас будет это на нормальном русском языке, да и вполне возможно, что лучшего качества и с дополнительными сведениями. Если так рассуждать дальше, можно сделать вывод, что ruSO вообще не нужен, всё есть на enSO, а если нет — то можно там и спросить.

Comment: @АндрейNOP будьте добры не игнорировать остальной текст ответа :) Я привёл конкретные примеры, к которым комментарии `лучшее качество и дополнительные сведения` применимы вряд ли. При этом я всеми руками и ногами ЗА хорошие вопросы и ответы, которые могут быть даже просто продублированы с enSO и переведены.

Comment: Вы не поверите: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50974446/2110496) Разместил вопрос просто потестить новый "мастер создания вопросов", заплюсовали, закрыли... Даже фраза "It's my homework" никого не повергла в ярость..

Comment: @vp_arth не совсем понял вопрос по ссылке, в чём соль? `actually question wizard testing`? Да и исключения могут быть и на enSO, я и не говорил во всём на него ориентироваться. Хотя их явно меньше.

Comment: "что, ruSO? не смеши, ты видел что там вообще задают и на что отвечают, о какой пользе речь?" - Мой опыт другой: "Что, ruSO? Я по твоему похож на мальчика для битья?"

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, не могли бы Вы добавить в ответ TL;DR? Резюме с кратким списком: бинайс.. что-то ещё?

Comment: Поддерживаю! Навязчивый бинайс — одна из очень сеьёзных проблем.

Comment: Если вы считаете эти вопросы некачественными, почему в них есть ваши ответы?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight почему, собственно, нет? Минусить/голосовать за закрытие мне это не мешало. Не отвечу я — ответят другие, либо вопрос закроют/удалят. Я человек простой, знаю ответ и не вижу других ответов — пишу, что знаю.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Потому что это не очень эффективный способ борьбы за качество вопросов. Наличие заплюсованных ответов защищает вопросы от автоудаления, даже если они закрыты.  Если на некачественные вопросы отвечать, их закономерно будет становиться все больше и больше.

Comment: Полностью согласен с автором. Можно было бы проголосовать "за" 10 раз - проголосовал бы точно. Плюс хотел бы заметить, что кое-где видел, как на вопрос "а почему вы на ruSO не отвечаете?" несколько довольно грамотных в своей профессиональной области человек дружно ответили в духе "да там одни дебилы задают тупые вопросы, а другие дебилы дают на них тупые (а то и просто неправильные) ответы". Так что еще не факт, что если правила сделать строже, то аудитория уменьшится. А я в любом случае за качество, а не за количество.

Comment: Я попробовал сформулировать TLDR для вашего ответа. Проверьте/поправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score -3):

**UPD**

Кажется, меня неправильно поняли (да я и сам себя только сейчас понял), поэтому основная мысль (это моя версия происходящего - "я художник, я так вижу этот мир" (c)) выглядит как-то так

**TL;DR**

Недовольство "бинайсом" со стороны отдельных участников идет от того, что они не видят достаточных технических возможностей влиять на некачественные вопросы и ответы, поэтому выливают негатив непосредственно на виновников ("тупых пользователей"), а также не видят понимания сути проблемы со стороны администрации.

---

**"Бинайсность"**

Я долго думал, что у ruSO нет особых проблем. Но раз вы считаете, что есть - ну пусть будет "есть".

Я про "бинайсность" выскажусь.

Сначала пара теоретических соображений. SO - это трехстроннее сотрудничество. Есть люди, у которых проблемы, есть люди, которые могут решать проблемы, и есть сайт, который помогает первым двум категориям найти друг друга. В качестве "комиссии" сайт показывает рекламу. Интересы сторон очевидны.

В чем мне видится ошибка администрации: администрация считает, что раз спрашивающих больше, то надо привлекать их. Отсюда - "бинайсность": нельзя называть дурака дураком, даже если он не просто дурак, а законченный идиот. Но у отвечающих нет никаких иных рычагов воздействия на идиотов. Планку надо как-то держать, иначе SO превратится в "Ответы@mail.ru". Мало кто сможет годами биться головой в эту стену. Я пока спасаюсь настройкой фильтров. У меня есть **оценочное суждение**, что качество вопросов и ответов по базам данных, где так или иначе упоминается MySQL или PHP, существенно ниже среднего по "БД вообще". Я пока настроил интерфейс так, чтобы просто не видеть эти вопросы.

У меня есть мнение, что если поднять планку требований к вопросам, то отвечающим станет интереснее писать хорошие содержательные ответы, и вот именно хорошие содержательные ответы будут нагонять качественный трафик, а не просто "у нас 100500 пользователей и 1048576 сообщений".

---

Честно говоря, я не знаю, как решить эту проблему. Все, что у меня есть - это кнопка "тревога", но тревоги неделями висят в ожидании. Какой в них толк тогда? Закрывать совсем тупые вопросы по базам данных своим единоличным решением я смогу лет через 10, не раньше (сейчас у меня 95 баллов за oracle за неполный год активного отвечания на вопросы). А тупые вопросы по смежным областям - на ruSO, видимо, никогда.

Comment: "*Но у отвечающих нет никаких иных рычагов воздействия на идиотов*" - минусы? Вы знаете о механизме блокировки за низкое качество (question ban)?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight А другие идиоты в это время плюсуют...

Comment: Да, бывает. Но все же, надежда на то что нормальных больше, или на то что "идиотам" лень голосовать

Comment: Содержательные вопросы и сейчас есть, только висят без ответа месяцами. А ещё их очень сложно формулировать, я над некоторыми думаю по полгодами. Нет никакой проблемы содержать сайт ответов на новичковые вопросы, к более серьёзному ru so не готов - проще искать счастья на en so. А на ruso и так сидит три человека и они уже давно проиграли [битву за трафик автоматическим переводам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/213987). Наш управляющий уже несколько лет не может переделать движок, чтобы яндекс хорошо индексировал и ничего не может сделать, чтобы спам-сайты не создавались как грибы.

Comment: @AK: Это действительно так? У нас и правда не хватает отвечающих? В этом случае мне совершенно неясна политика «незаменимых у нас нет». Впрочем, падение качества переводов вследствие такой политики уже очевидно.

Comment: @VladD я почти не отвечаю, т.к. интересных вопросов с каждым месяцев всё меньше и меньше. Всё больше третьесортных вопросов, среди которых пачкаться не хочу. Но на них найдётся свой отвечающий. Который прокачает рейтинг до определённого уровня и ему тоже надоест. И т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение! Читаю ответ и вижу постоянную оценочную характеристику, где начало точки отсчета — вы. В этом вся соль. Пожалуйста, проделайте следующий мысленный эксперимент. Установите точку отсчета на уровень знаний специалиста, который знает раза в три больше и глубже вас. Теперь именно вы автор тех вопросов, про которые вы говорите. Прочитайте еще раз ваш ответ. И еще раз. Все еще считаете себя тем, про кого вы написали? Вам хочется взаимодействовать со спецами, которые считают вас тем, о ком вы написали?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky В топку ваши мысленные эксперименты. Идите в мой профиль, читайте вопросы, которые я задавал. Про них можно сказать, что они тупые и бессмысленные? Если да - скажите, какие именно. Если нет - приведите специалиста, который знает в три раза больше меня, пусть он скажет. Остальное мне неинтересно.

Comment: Попробуйте, пожалуйста сделать TLDR покороче, на манер с другими ответами. Это заметно облегчит понимание ответа.

Comment: @Kromster Попробую, но не гарантирую, что получится

Comment: @Kromster Сделал, короче чем сейчас не могу. Проще удалить совсем.

Answer (score -11):

Тыщу лет не был, но всё-таки..

Для мненя этот ресурс бесполезен. Ответы на свои вопросы я быстрей найду лично, а не тут. Отвечать? Вы серъёзно, при том что ссылки в гугл или маны не приветствуются?

Поржать над идиотами тоже вроде не политкорректно, школьников  послать  в школу -тоже. Негров называть неграми тоже нельзя?

Answer (score -11):

Неверные принципы построения сообщества:

1. система рейтинга сама по себе зло. Истина не определяется голосованием. А оценивать других людей - грех.
2. возможность редактировать чужие сообщения
3. отсутствие правил
4. модерирующие боты - верх оскорбления участников
5. "модераторы" - платные агитаторы, которым компании платят за рекламу своих технологий и которые ненавидят "умников", которые им мешают деньги зарабатывать. Поскольку такой человека как правило обладает поверхностными техническими знаниями, каждый неудобный вопрос для него как кость в горле.
6. неуважение к интеллекту
7. нелюбовь истины

Comment: *оценивать других людей - грех.* - но в тоже время вы оценили модераторов, т.е. Вам оценивать можно, Вас оценивать нельзя. насчет отсутствие нарушение не согласен: 5 пункт весьма спорный.

Comment: Никто тут не платит модераторам.

Answer (score -14):

Я ***НЕНАВИЖУ*** когда редактируют мои сообщения без спроса. Бывают и адекватные ситуации, когда действительно улучшают мой ответ/вопрос, делая пример кода более наглядным, улучшают читаемость и оформление сообщения и всё такое. Но в подавляющем большинстве случаев люди просто лезут, чтобы удалить кусок моего текста, считая, по своему мнению, его несправедливым, правят грамматику до каждой запятой, перестраивают целые предложения, переписывают мой код. Я хочу, чтобы мои сообщения выглядели в таком стиле, в котором я их составил, это очевидно. Причём редактировать сообщения может почти каждый, из за низкого порога репутации.

Почему бы не сделать так: пускай без спросу вопросы и ответы под ними могут редактировать только участники, у которых есть золотая медаль по одному из тэгов вопроса, а чтобы вступили в силу редактирования всех остальных, нужно подтверждение от автора этого сообщения? Я уверен, это будет справедливым решением.

Comment: Порог репутации для самостоятельного редактирования 2000, Вы ведь его ещё не достигли, почему вы считаете его низким? А если бы Вы ознакомились с правилами(отсутствие знака Информированный, как бы намекает), Вы бы знали, что любой размещённый контент принадлежит не Вам, а "сообществу". Содержимое [попадает](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) под действие лицензии `cc by-sa 3.0`. С другой стороны, всегда можно вежливо обратиться к другому участнику - часто у нас прислушиваются к подобным желаниям и вместо редактирования начинают указывать на недостатки в комментариях

Comment: @vp_arth ну дак имея 2к репутации и получив её, например, за тонны вопросов по html, пользователь может пойти и начать править всё подряд, вопросы по js, с# например и т.д. будучи некомпетентным во всём и просто желая поправить грамматику. Фильтрация по золотой медальке всёравно была бы справедливее. И в любом случае, кому бы там не принадлежало моё сообщение, но возможность его исправлять только приносит мне неудобства, из за необходимости каждый раз исправлять всё обратно, как было. Удобство пользователей ведь превыше неких локальных понятий?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что наше сообщество - локальная ветка английского SO? Изменения правил, которые вы предлагаете невозможно провести только тут. Можно попробовать предложить их там, но для этого, как минимум, стоит убедиться, что эти изменения нужны не только Вам хотя бы тут. Создайте, пожалуйста, отдельный пост с этой конкретной проблемой на мете

Comment: @vp_arth да да, конечно, просто если зашла речь о проблеме сообщества, то вот пожалуйста, описанная мной - самая главная на данный момент, по моему скромному мнению.

Comment: Если считаете правку несправедливой ее всегда можно откатить

Comment: @yolosora в том и проблема, я чаще откатываю, чем соглашаюсь с исправляющим. Поэтому считаю, что лучше сделать наоборот: если я считаю правку справедливой я всегда могу её принять.

Comment: Как я понимаю, всё написанное там актуально до сих пор: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5675

Comment: Очень спорный момент по поводу редактирования, потому что: вполне кто-то может *не любит* читать текст с *ошибками описками*, художествееное введение *"Доброго всем. Я тут после долгих попыток"* на 10 строк, *вставки* которые отношение к вопросу не имеют, а иногда просто *неправильно построеные предложения* с вставками *слов-паразитов*. (я просто перечислил что встречается не читая чьих либо вопросов) Хочется видеть в вопросах коротко и по-существу. Часто авторы не заморачиваются и допускают описаное выше.

Comment: Кому и кобыла невеста. Я бы наоборот запретил писать тут всяким любителям писать "попробывать", "ньюанс", "тся"/"ться" где не надо, пропускателям запятых, точек и заглавных букв. Некоторые даже в начале предложения не способны написать заглавную букву. Даже когда предложение всего одно...

Comment: @Diskyp а вот за это - *"чаще откатываю, чем соглашаюсь с исправляющим"* - можно и бан получить, кстати. За вандализм. Если ваши сообщения часто кто-то правит не в тему - лучше обсудить эти правки на мете или в чате вместо того чтобы втихую откатывать их.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну и чем это противоречит моему предложению? Вносите правки и объясните автору, почему ему стоит их принять. Если причины справедливы - человек от правки не откажется. А то, что вы считаете себя исключительно правым в любой ситуации и меняете изложение автора сообщения как хотите, я считаю несправедливым.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну етить я вандал, свой стиль оформления сообщений отстаиваю против тех, кто мне его меняет по своему усмотрению. Пускай лучше объясняются те, кто мне исправления вносят, а не втихушку редактируют. Так разве не логичнее?

Comment: @Diskyp но для этого вы должны их спросить, а не в тихую откатывать правки.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы повторяетесь.

Comment: @nick_n_a А как вы смотрите на правки в самом коде, написанном в ответе? К примеру была изменена переменная, или адрес сервера, и не был уведомлен автор ответа, что в его код внесена правка?

Comment: @Anamnian в вашем случае вы не описали всю модель. Есть понятие модель, если вы готовы предложить свою модель - предложите. Модель без редактирования либо с участием автора - не подходит, поскольку некоторые задав вопрос - могут годами не появлятся на сайте или вообще не появлятся. Т.е. есть проблема, если это проблема с моделью механизма правок - то можно рассмотреть другие модели механизмов правок. Возможно большинству понравится другая модель. А пока что прийдётся считаться с такой моделью. Кстати, автор уведомление получает. Правда уведомление, а не вопрос хочет он правку или нет.

Comment: @nick_n_a речь была про редактирование ответа, а не вопроса. Потому как был инцидент- один пользователь с большой репутацией внес изменения в мой код в ответе, и не указал на это в комментариях. Если бы я не заметил надписи изменен под ответом, я мог бы вообще не догадаться что кто-то изменил мой код. И между прочим эта правка кардинально меняла смысл кода.

Comment: @Anamnian Я такой момент не помню что б попадался... как правило я правку своих видел сразу. Если и правда такой баг есть - то нужно написать отдельным вопросом на мете.

Comment: @nick_n_a Возможно это только для пользователей с низкой репутацией- недавно мне сделали правку в ответе и я получил об этом уведомление.

Comment: @Anamnian открою вам секрет: надпись "изменен" под ответом именно для того и нужна

Comment: @PavelMayorov мне кажется мы уже выяснили все моменты в соответствующем вопросе, но вам это не дает покоя? Вы правы, я не прав. Вопрос исчерпан.